# gawk replace column and increment but not for all lines

Tags: awk, replace, gsub

I want to replace the second column in the file below but not for all lines.

I tried this:
`gawk 'BEGIN{a=0} {gsub($2, a++); print $0}' filein > fileout;`

But it partly messes up some lines, for example where it says TER and END.

Filein looks like this:
`ATOM   6513  N   CYX D 438       6.267 -19.583  33.328  1.00 99.72           N
ATOM   6514  CA  CYX D 438       5.026 -19.379  34.078  1.00 99.72           C
ATOM   6515  C   CYX D 438       5.441 -19.597  35.520  1.00 99.72           C
ATOM   6516  O   CYX D 438       4.662 -19.960  36.400  1.00 99.72           O
ATOM   6517  CB  CYX D 438       3.940 -20.381  33.611  1.00 99.72           C
ATOM   6518  SG  CYX D 438       3.155 -19.991  32.020  1.00 99.72           S
TER
HETATM    1  C1  L35   900     -11.042 -69.780 -18.443  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    2  C2  L35   900      -9.989 -68.975 -18.009  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    3  C3  L35   900     -11.968 -70.232 -17.506  1.00  0.00           C
CONECT  324 1315
CONECT 2005 2938
CONECT 3228 6518
CONECT 3528 4682
CONECT 5373 6190
ENDMDL
END`

I want the file to look like this:

`ATOM   1  N   CYX D 438       6.267 -19.583  33.328  1.00 99.72           N
ATOM   2  CA  CYX D 438       5.026 -19.379  34.078  1.00 99.72           C
ATOM   3  C   CYX D 438       5.441 -19.597  35.520  1.00 99.72           C
ATOM   4  O   CYX D 438       4.662 -19.960  36.400  1.00 99.72           O
ATOM   5  CB  CYX D 438       3.940 -20.381  33.611  1.00 99.72           C
ATOM   6  SG  CYX D 438       3.155 -19.991  32.020  1.00 99.72           S
TER
HETATM    7  C1  L35   900     -11.042 -69.780 -18.443  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    8  C2  L35   900      -9.989 -68.975 -18.009  1.00  0.00           C
HETATM    9  C3  L35   900     -11.968 -70.232 -17.506  1.00  0.00           C
CONECT  324 1315
CONECT 2005 2938
CONECT 3228 6518
CONECT 3528 4682
CONECT 5373 6190
ENDMDL
END`

Comment: What does your `fileout` look like ?

Comment: gawk is one variant of awk. **FAR** more people will see your question if you tag it with awk instead of, or in addition to, gawk. You'd probably have had your answer weeks ago.